# Variable Accessing Problem

Tags: variables, actionscript, programming-languages

can anyone help me in ActionScript!

I created a movieclip called **holder** in my Stage and I name it, inside them i put a variable called

**name = "whatever"**

Now I can't access the variable from root timeline, I try this:

**trace(holder.name);**

The result gives me undefined! what mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually declared the instance name of holder? If not, you have to make sure the holder's instance name is set. Also, I believe that 'name' is a reserved property for objects in Actionscript. In fact, there really is no need to even set it within the movieclip. Calling Object.name will return it's instance name anyway.

Comment: What version of actionscript are you using? For 2.0, then trace(holder._name) should work, in 3.0, trace(holder.name) should work without having to declaring it within the movieclip

Comment: For got to add, instead of giving each one a 'name' variable inside it, just declare it's instance name as whatever you want to call it. Unless you want to store other bits of information inside, in which case you should use an object, or ideally a new class in 3